# Tessract error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError when minifyenable is true

Tags: android, minify, tesseract, android-proguard

I'm receiving the error bellow when I build my app with minifyenable true. The odd is when I compile with minifyenable false the app works fine. The apps uses Tesseract in order to Scan documents.

What am I missing?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeData" in class "Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;" or its superclasses
    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.cfb.doarnf.el.a(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.cfb.doarnf.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.cfb.doarnf.a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.cfb.doarnf"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':tess-two')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:tess-two)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. Just avoided ProGuard to process tess-two library, following this:

**Adding consumerProguardFiles to build.gradle (Module:tess-two)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-tess-two-rules.txt'
    }


    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

**proguard-tess-two-rules.txt File**

```
# Add tess-two specific ProGuard rules here.
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontnote
```

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: Thanks, You pointed me in the right direction. We only need 3 rules though. `-dontoptimize,-dontpreverify,-dontshrink`

Comment: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/ecb4219ceaa1dba01a834102e3275fce2996ffed/tess-two/proguard-rules.pro

Adding the proguard rules from the tess two repo fixed the issue for me. I was using Xamarin and I had to create a custom proguard rule file with the above. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows